# Devise token auth skip update auth header on deleting user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I'm using devise_token_auth 1.1.3 and devise 4.4.3 together in my Rails application and I'm trying to remove the current user. My users are called 'staff'. The problem is when I try and delete the current user it tries to update the auth header for a user which doesn't exist.

```
  def destroy
    staff = Staff.find(params[:id])

    if current_staff.entity == staff.entity
      staff.destroy
      render json: { success: "Staff Member Successfully Deleted" }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { success: "Staff Member failed to delete" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Within that render json line it hits this line in devise_token_auth and crashes;

```
devise_token_auth (1.1.3) app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb:105:in `update_auth_header'
```

**Update: Try and use the registrations controller to delete user**

I've set the current route overrides

```
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Staff', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    sessions: 'sessions',
    registrations: 'registrations'
  }
```

And overridden the registrations controller like so;

```
class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController

  def destroy
    puts 'test'
    byebug
  end

end
```

Now in my test if I call

```
    delete "/auth/#{staff.id}"
```

It doesn't hit the byebug at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to add the following line of code at the top of your controller:

```
skip_after_action :update_auth_header, only: %i[destroy]
```

What this does is skip the update_auth_header after action defined in devise only for the "destroy" method.